# Automatic CSV file generation, with header in two title levels with different number of columns with Oracle 10g

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, export-to-csv

We have an application that uses Oracle 10g R. 10.2.0.4.0. I need to create a procedure that exports the data for a given query to a CSV file in a specific layout, so that it can be imported into another application.

I found the following link that helped me a lot. This procedure uses `utl_file` and allows me to put the queries I need in the `l_query` field.

[Export to CSV - By Ask TOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:88212348059)

The file I need to generate has the following structure:

```
Title;9999
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4;FIELD5
1234;30032021;0400;093000;123000
1235;30032021;0400;133000;183000
```

I created the titles in two levels, one to put a title for the file with two fields, and the other with the title of the columns of the data that the application will load. I achieved this using `UNION ALL`. I found two problems that I can't solve, however:

1. I can't remove the headers from the query block
2. As I used `UNION ALL`, the first blocking query forces me to have the number of fields that I need to generate the information in the following queries (five fields), and for that reason the file is generated with two headers, and in the second is generated with three `;;;` that I need to remove.

   Title;9999;'';'';'';                   --I need to remove this header
   Title;9999; ; ;                        --I need to remove the three  ";;;"
   FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4;FIELD5
   1234;08042021;123;224130;044130
   1235;08042021;123;224130;044130
   1236;08042021;123;224130;044130

This was the procedure that I adapted with the query that I created in the variable `l_query`.

```
create or replace procedure dump_table_to_csv(p_dir in varchar2, p_filename in varchar2 )
is
l_output utl_file.file_type;
l_theCursor integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
l_columnValue varchar2(4000);
l_status integer;
l_query varchar2(4000)
default 
  'SELECT ''Title'' AS "Title",  ''9999'' AS "9999" , '' '', '' '', '' ''  from DUAL 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT TO_CHAR(''FIELD1'') AS FIELD1, TO_CHAR(''FIELD2'') AS FIELD2, TO_CHAR(''FIELD3'') AS FIELD3, TO_CHAR(''FIELD4'') AS FIELD4, TO_CHAR(''FIELD5'') AS FIELD5 FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
   TO_CHAR(''9999'') AS FIELD1
   ,TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, ''DDMMYYYY'') AS FIELD2 
   ,''123'' AS FIELD3
   ,LPAD(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, ''HH24MISS''), 6, 0) AS FIELD4
   ,LPAD(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + INTERVAL ''6:00'' HOUR TO MINUTE, ''HH24MISS''), 6, 0) AS FILED5 
 FROM DUAL';
    
l_colCnt number := 0;
l_separator varchar2(1);
l_descTbl dbms_sql.desc_tab;
begin
l_output := utl_file.fopen( p_dir, p_filename, 'w', 4000 ); 
execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'' ';
dbms_sql.parse( l_theCursor, l_query, dbms_sql.native );
dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl );

for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || '' || l_descTbl(i).col_name || ';' );
dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000 );
l_separator := '';
end loop;
utl_file.new_line( l_output );
l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);
while ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 ) loop
l_separator := '';
for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );
utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || l_columnValue );
l_separator := ';';
end loop;
utl_file.new_line( l_output );
end loop;
dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_theCursor);
utl_file.fclose( l_output );
execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-MON-yy'' ';
exception
when others then
execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-MON-yy'' ';
raise;
end;
/



EXEC  dump_table_to_csv('MY_DIRECTORY', 'file_to_export.csv' );
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem, or point me to some other way to achieve my goal, and generate this file in the correct structure?

Comment: You might try [this refcursor to csv converter](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml), though I don't know whether it will work in 10.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first header line doesn't appear to depend on the structure of the query, I'd just use a single `utl_file.put_line` to print that out first and leave the rest of Tom's procedure basically unchanged

```
create or replace procedure dump_table_to_csv(p_dir in varchar2, 
                                              p_filename in varchar2 )
is
  l_output utl_file.file_type;
  l_theCursor integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  l_columnValue varchar2(4000);
  l_status integer;
  l_query varchar2(4000) :=
    q'{SELECT
           TO_CHAR(''9999'') AS FIELD1
          ,TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, ''DDMMYYYY'') AS FIELD2 
          ,'123' AS FIELD3
          ,LPAD(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24MISS'), 6, 0) AS FIELD4
          ,LPAD(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + INTERVAL '6:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'HH24MISS'), 6, 0) AS FILED5 
      FROM DUAL}';
    
  l_colCnt number := 0;   
  l_separator varchar2(1);
  l_descTbl dbms_sql.desc_tab;
begin
  l_output := utl_file.fopen( p_dir, p_filename, 'w', 4000 ); 
  execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'' ';
  dbms_sql.parse( l_theCursor, l_query, dbms_sql.native );
  dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl );

  utl_file.put_line( 'Title;9999' );
  for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
    utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || '' || l_descTbl(i).col_name || ';' );
    dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000 );
    l_separator := '';
  end loop;
  utl_file.new_line( l_output );

  l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);
  while ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 ) 
  loop
    l_separator := '';
    for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
      dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );
      utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || l_columnValue );
      l_separator := ';';
    end loop;
    utl_file.new_line( l_output );
  end loop;
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_theCursor);
  utl_file.fclose( l_output );
  execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-MON-yy'' ';
exception
when others then
  execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-MON-yy'' ';
  raise;
end;
/
```